# Knapsack Variation (Fixed amount, different types)

Tags: algorithms, knapsack-problems

I'm trying to figure out a variation to the knapsack problem.  The major difference is all objects have a type.  For an example we can call them type A, B, C, D, and E.  In addition to this we have to have a specific amount of each type.  For example get the most value in the knapsack as possible while using 1 item of type A, 2 of type B, 3 of type C, 1 of type D, 1 of type E, and 1 that can be either B, C, or D.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Doesn't a slight alteration to the usual dynamic programming scheme do it? If not, what did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I was looking at the 0/1 solution where you build the two dimensional array.  However, I didn't think that would really help me in this situation.  I'm not sure how I would limit the items to a set amount, and check for types.  If there is another solution that you're thinking of I would love to hear it.  I'm just not sure how else to attack this.